# Formula For Bill Budgeting

Tags: excel

Hello I have an example of what I need a formula for:

Joe has $500 in his checking account. He has 5 monthly bills: Electric is $100, Water is $50, Cell phone is $70, Car note is $350 and Loan payment is $250. Joe wants to know how much money can he put towards each bill based off of what he has in his checking account.

I need a formula for this. I hope this example makes sense!

Comment: so you want a weighted average?

Comment: And what is the monthly income?

Comment: Your basic formula will be something like `500/(100+50+70+350+250)` then multiply the answer to that against each cost.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think i figured it out to get fixed proportions:

| + | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Balance |  |  |
| 2 |  |  |  |
| 3 | Bill | Owe | Pay |
| 4 | Electric | 100 | 60.98 |
| 5 | Water | 50 | 30.49 |
| 6 | Cell phone | 70 | 42.68 |
| 7 | Car note | 350 | 213.41 |
| 8 | Loan | 250 | 152.44 |
| 9 | Total | 820 | 500.00 |

Where the formula in C4 is:

```
=B4/SUM($B$4:$B$8)*$B$1
```

which can be dragged down column C to row 9. And row 10 is simply the `SUM` of rows 4 to 9.